# unable to insert record in database

Tags: php, mysql

my basic insert query is not working.. i know its a very basic, raw sort of question to ask but m unable to sort out

my code

```
 $a="nvsdjkvn";
    $b="bhjxcbncj";
    mysql_select_db("vas1",$con);
    $s = "insert into updates(update,dates) values ('$b','$a')";
    $re = mysql_query($s);
```

i got this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update,dates) values ('nvsdjkvn','bhjxcbncj')' at line 1
```

my table name is: updates with two columns 'update' and 'dates' both of type 'varchar'

Comment: `mysql_` functions are depreciated. consider moving to mysqli or PDO, as per your question.. make sure all fields exist, you have a table with that name.. etc.

Comment: Use `insert into updates('update',dates) values ('$b','$a')`.

Comment: put a space between `updates` and `(update,dates)`

Comment: @YotamOmer: "Deprecated".  No "i".  Sorry, that's a pet peeve of mine.  :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update` is a reserved word in SQL and must therefore be enclosed in backticks if not used as a reserved word:

```
$s = "insert into updates(`update`,dates) values ('$b','$a')";
```

Answer (score 2):

`UPDATE` is a reserved word in MySQL. To use in your query, you should properly escape it.

Here is a [complete list of MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html).

Answer (score 1):

Change -

```
$s = "insert into updates(update,dates) values ('$b','$a')";
```

To

```
$s = "insert into updates(`update`,`dates`) values ('".$b."','".$a."')";
```

> Mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended
>   for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead,
>   either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also the
>   MySQL API Overview for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid to say so but we are not allowed to name a table just like a keyword.
Please go through the rule set for naming conventions

http://www.isbe.state.il.us/ILDS/pdf/SQL_server_standards.pdf‎

Comment: I linkified your link for you.  At best, though, realize that that is not "the rule set".  Those are guidelines and not hard-set rules.  And they're not exactly "standards" outside of ILDS.

Comment: True. Thanks for rectifying and making me aware :)